# Font Awesome Icons not showing after GetSimple CMS implementation

Tags: html, web-deployment, frontend, webfonts, font-awesome

I got stuck on a problem and hope some of you can help me out. I created a company web page and integrated Font Awesome. 
I made an static version of the page based on HTML5, CSS3, jQuery and all works great. 
Due to the fact that my customer can make his own small content editing I tried to implement my static web page into GetSimple CMS.

Everything works just great except for the fact that the Font Awesome fonts are not showing up.

In order to exclude the error that I made an path error with the css or the font files I tried to track them down and addressed them absolut.

In my opinion the files are integrated properly.

Does someone know if theres something special to make when integrating fonts into GetSimple CMS?

It would be nice if someone can give me an advice,
many thanks,
greetings.

Some Images as attachment (Dropbox Folder Link):
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ajha139zt9kmi7r/qilSDA813w

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hosting the fonts on your site, have you considered using a CDN? Just replace the font awesome CSS call in the head of your template with

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and you are good to go.

In addition to removing a lot of potential problems, you usually get a performance boost as 
well.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. As I found out, everything was done right. The problem was that the cms-editor removed empty tags. So all <i class="fa fa-xy"></i> tags were "cleaned" up by the editor. Solution can be found here: [link](http://get-simple.info/forums/showthread.php?tid=6094)

Comment: Good going, I've had that same issue with editors and font awesome in other frameworks.